# long miscalculates

Tags: c#

What is wrong with the long datatype in the following code which returns -666167296 with time=42 and TimeStyle.Days?

```
    private long ConvertToMilliSeconds(int time, TimeStyle style)
    {
        long t = 0;
        switch (style)
        {
            case TimeStyle.Millisecons:
                t = time;
                break;
            case TimeStyle.Seconds:
                t = time * 1000;
                break;
            case TimeStyle.Minutes:
                t = time * 1000 * 60;
                break;
            case TimeStyle.Hours:
                t = time * 1000 * 60 * 60;
                break;
            case TimeStyle.Days:
                t = time * 86400000;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return t;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`time` is an `int`, make it `long` or cast to `long` or `* 86400000L`

Answer (score 3):

When you do a calculation like this:

```
t = time * 86400000
```

the fact that `t` is a `long` is irrelevant: the arithmetic on the right hand side of the assignment operator is performed in 32 bits, because `time` and `86400000` are both `int` values. You need the operation to be performed in `long` arithmetic to avoid overflow.

Given that it's reasonable to have a `long` number of milliseconds, I would just change `t` to a `long`. I'd also throw an exception if the enum value isn't recognized, rather than just returning 0:

```
private static long ConvertToMilliSeconds(long time, TimeStyle style)
{
    switch (style)
    {
        // Note: fixed typo in enum name
        case TimeStyle.Milliseconds: return time;
        case TimeStyle.Seconds:      return time * 1000;
        case TimeStyle.Minutes:      return time * 1000 * 60;
        case TimeStyle.Hours:        return time * 1000 * 60 * 60;
        case TimeStyle.Days:         return time * 86400000;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("style");
    }
}
```

You might also want to change those values to constants:

```
private const long MillisecondsPerSecond = 1000;
private const long MillisecondsPerMinute = MillisecondsPerSecond * 60;
private const long MillisecondsPerHour = MillisecondsPerMinute * 60;
private const long MillisecondsPerDay = MillisecondsPerHour * 24;
```

... and use those in the method.

Finally, to avoid any possible confusion where you've got values in the wrong units, you might want to just use `TimeSpan` to start with... and if you're still finding that date/time APIs are painful, you might want to look at my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) library :)

Answer (score 0):

42 * 86400000 is to big for long. if i type it in visual-studio i get a compiler error:

> The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode

Comment: This answer is incorrect; 42 * 86400000 is not too big for long.  Instead, 42 * 86400000 is an `int` expression, and the result *is* too big for int, which is why you get the compiler error.